# Why can't I call it UDPClient?

Tags: python, pycharm

I use Pycharm and it can't identify python file named UDPClient.py,even UDPclient.py have no problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cZVJ.png)

Comment: What filesystem are you running?

Comment: So, you can `import UDPclient` but when you try `import UDPClient` something goes wrong? If so, what?

Comment: It would help to post the file directory as text, not a png. This keeps the data in the question and lets us test whether there is some funky character in your file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Pycharm Settings -> Editor -> File Types.

It is possible you have accidently added "UDPClient.py" into "File name patterns" for Text or other type. [image]

Comment: thanks,i find it in Automatically detect file type by content